# How to deny update permissions to one SQL table, but allow for others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table, foo-1, that I want to deny update permissions to, but not change the permissions for this existing user for any of the other tables.  I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
--All 
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT ON Customers TO Joe, Mary


--Revoke UPDATE access to table Customers for user Joe
REVOKE UPDATE ON Customers to Joe

--Cant Delete
DENY DELETE ON Customers to Joe, Mary

--Can Exec StoredProcedure
GRANT EXEC ON uspInsertCustomers TO Joe

--Grant Create Table
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Joe
```

This Displays User Info

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[List_DBRoles]

(

@database nvarchar(128)=null,

@user varchar(20)=null,

@dbo char(1)=null,

@access char(1)=null,

@security char(1)=null,

@ddl char(1)=null,

@datareader char(1)=null,

@datawriter char(1)=null,

@denyread char(1)=null,

@denywrite char(1)=null

)

as

declare @dbname varchar(200)

declare @mSql1 varchar(8000)

CREATE TABLE #DBROLES

( DBName sysname not null,

UserName sysname not null,

db_owner varchar(3) not null,

db_accessadmin varchar(3) not null,

db_securityadmin varchar(3) not null,

db_ddladmin varchar(3) not null,

db_datareader varchar(3) not null,

db_datawriter varchar(3) not null,

db_denydatareader varchar(3) not null,

db_denydatawriter varchar(3) not null,

Cur_Date datetime not null default getdate()

)



DECLARE DBName_Cursor CURSOR FOR

select name

from master.dbo.sysdatabases

where name not in ('mssecurity','tempdb')

Order by name

OPEN DBName_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM DBName_Cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

Set @mSQL1 = ' Insert into #DBROLES ( DBName, UserName, db_owner, db_accessadmin,

db_securityadmin, db_ddladmin, db_datareader, db_datawriter,

db_denydatareader, db_denydatawriter )

SELECT '+''''+@dbName +''''+ ' as DBName ,UserName, '+char(13)+ '

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_owner'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_owner,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_accessadmin '' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_accessadmin ,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_securityadmin'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_securityadmin,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_ddladmin'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_ddladmin,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_datareader'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_datareader,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_datawriter'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_datawriter,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_denydatareader'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_denydatareader,

Max(CASE RoleName WHEN ''db_denydatawriter'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END) AS db_denydatawriter

from (

select b.name as USERName, c.name as RoleName

from ' + @dbName+'.dbo.sysmembers a '+char(13)+

' join '+ @dbName+'.dbo.sysusers b '+char(13)+

' on a.memberuid = b.uid join '+@dbName +'.dbo.sysusers c

on a.groupuid = c.uid )s

Group by USERName

order by UserName'

--Print @mSql1

Execute (@mSql1)

FETCH NEXT FROM DBName_Cursor INTO @dbname

END

CLOSE DBName_Cursor

DEALLOCATE DBName_Cursor

Select * from #DBRoles

where ((@database is null) OR (DBName LIKE '%'+@database+'%')) AND

((@user is null) OR (UserName LIKE '%'+@user+'%')) AND

((@dbo is null) OR (db_owner = 'Yes')) AND

((@access is null) OR (db_accessadmin = 'Yes')) AND

((@security is null) OR (db_securityadmin = 'Yes')) AND

((@ddl is null) OR (db_ddladmin = 'Yes')) AND

((@datareader is null) OR (db_datareader = 'Yes')) AND

((@datawriter is null) OR (db_datawriter = 'Yes')) AND

((@denyread is null) OR (db_denydatareader = 'Yes')) AND

((@denywrite is null) OR (db_denydatawriter = 'Yes'))
```

Comment: Also note that `DENY` trumps any `GRANT` while `REVOKE` just removes the `GRANT` (or `DENY`).  So if you `DENY` a permission you will not be able to `GRANT` it back in any way short of making the user `DBO` or `sysadmin` or of course you can `REVOKE` the `DENY`.